# Finding highest frequency of letters in a sentence - python

Tags: python

I am a beginner with python and I want to make a program that can show the highest frequency of a letter in a given sentence. But, the program only works with one value, and only displays one of the letters that has the highest frequency.

I've already tried creating a list so that the biggest values will be added to it so that it will display multiple letters with their values. But, the problem is that the first value will always appear because it's greater than 0.

```py
sentencecount = input("Please enter a sentence:\n")
print(f"The length of your sentence is {len(sentencecount)}.")
lettercount = {}
for i in sentencecount:
    if i in lettercount:
        lettercount[i] += 1
    else:
        lettercount[i] = 1
print(lettercount)
maximum=0
x='a'
listofletters = []
for x, y in lettercount.items():
    if y >= maximum:
        maximum=y
        letter =x
        listofletters.append(letter)
        listofletters.append(maximum)
print(listofletters)
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: The last for loop will sequentially iterate and pick the letters with count greater than the previous one. So, it is not deterministic. Can you clarify your requirement? Do you top 1 or top 3 or what? You may sort to pick top n values from lettercount.

Comment: this may help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter (`counter = Counter(sentence.lower().strip())`).

Comment: I want to make it so that if the sentence was "aaaabbbbcccc" it would display a was repeated 4 times, b was repeated 4 times, and c was repeated 4 times. If it was "aabbc", it would only display that a and b were both repeated twice because they appeared the most times.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = "aaaabbbbcccc"

counter = Counter(sentence.lower().strip())
print(counter)  # Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 4})
print(counter.most_common(1))  # [('a', 4)]
```

the `lower()` and `strip()` methods ensure you get the same result as above for `'a Aaabb Bbc cc C'`.

if you wanted to select all the letters that are the most frequent:

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = "aaaabbbbcccc"

counter = Counter(sentence.lower().strip())
most_common = counter.most_common()

max_occurrence = most_common[0][1]
res = [letter for letter, occurrence in most_common if occurrence == max_occurrence]
 # ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of most occuring values,

```
from collections import Counter
#switch the string to lower case if needed
s="abbbcdacabda"
counts=dict(Counter(s))
most_occuring_letters = [k for k,v in counts.items() if v == max(counts.values())]
```

result - ['a','b']